# Cannot get Virtual PC to install on my machine

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I ran the tool to check that hardware virtualization is enabled, and it is (i7-2600).

I ran the proper version of the Virtual PC download (Windows 7 Professional x64) and  I can see the Windows Virtual PC (KB958559) update in my installed updates list.

The .msu file runs fine without errors, but even after multiple reboots I can't actually find a trace of Virtual PC anywhere. There is nothing in program files, the start menu, or system32.

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Have you attempted to install KB958559 and KB977206 instead?  I am unable to find KB98559 on the internet, the first page of results is a bunch of non-english sites and this question.  Where exactly are you looking?

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry. That was a typo. I haven't downloaded KB977206, I didn't think I needed it since my machine should have all the required pre-reqs. However, I'll try it and update the question later. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Ramhound, It says that KB977206 is not applicable to my computer. I"m guessing because it already meets the per-requisites.

Comment: Are your trying to install XP mode? if so you must install XP mode first.

Comment: @Moab, No, just Virtual PC. I don't need XP Mode.

Comment: Maybe you need the full version of Virtual PC...http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4580

Answer (score 0):

Check the setup of your BIOS to enable Virtualization.

A useful article from MS: 
Configure BIOS for Hardware Assisted Virtualization (HAV) PCs
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/configure-bios.aspx

If nothings works after this check for an alternative: Oracle VirtualBox:
https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: That was the tool I referred to in my question. It does say that my computer is already configured with hardware assisted virtualization and that I can proceed with the installation. I'll take a look at virtualbox though. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There should be a "Windows Virtual PC" entry in the start menu under All Programs. Click on the "Windows Virtual PC" then opens up the Windows Explorer with an extra menu entry for creating a new virtual machine. Also listed should be any existing virtual machines like the one created for XP Mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: theres not. That's the problem. I ran the installer, no errors came up, but nothing happened. Nothing in the Start Menu, Program Files, or anywhere else.